# Why is octal character not taking in Java?

Tags: java

Hi friends I have following.

```
 ch\u0061r bala =  '\u0061';
 ch\141r bal = '\141';
```

`ch\u0061r a = '\u0061'` is working  but `ch\141r a1 = '\141'` is nt taking as `char` in Java, both `\u0061` and `\141` are characters representing the character `a`.

Answer (score 4):

In java, Unicode characters (ie `\unnnn`) may be used anywhere - either in source code or character/String literals, but octal literals (ie `\nnn`) may only be used in character/String literals.

Comment: why unicode characters can be used any where but not octal characters

Comment: It's defined in the java language specification

Comment: @Bohemian:it is better to cite that

Comment: See the Chapter 3 sections [Lexical Translations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) and [Lexical Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) for details about how Java treats Unicode escape sequences. Octal is not treated in the same way (outside of literal Character and literal String definitions).

Comment: @laks true but I'm on my iPhone and it's a real hassle! Thankfully someone has come to the rescue